# how to show success message for each field in codeigniter

Tags: validation

how to show success message against each form field like we show error message for each field..when i write

```
<?if(form_error('username')) {
  //show error message
}
else
   // show success message
?>
```

it shows success message when the form is loaded without validating anything..

Comment: Ryan, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately to get an answer you're going to have to give a lot more detail.  Programming language, platform, sample code, what have you tried so far, etc?

Comment: ya..sorry for that..its php in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same way you would test to see if the form has already been submitted... (and don't use short tags)

```
<?php 
    if(form_error('username')) {
      //show error message
    } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['submit_button_value'])) {
       // show success message
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi calumbrodie,thnx for ur reply..but i am using a image as link button..so it does't hv any name,value..sorry for that..i m a novice with php & codeigniter

Comment: you should still be able to give it a value
     <input type="image" src="/images/graphics/button1.gif" value="submit_button_value" /> although this will give its own set of problems in IE. You could also just use a submit button and style it using css background image